# Error with dpkg, while upgrading packages on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, dpkg

That's command `sudo DEBCONF_DEBUG=developer apt upgrade -f`

And that's output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      kubectl libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common linux-libc-dev pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2 pgadmin4-common pgadmin4-doc snapd xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04
      xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04
    11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B/57,6 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 995 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    debconf (developer): starting /tmp/pgadmin4-apache2.config.cHqjgK configure 4.21-1.pgdg18.04+1
    debconf (developer): <-- INPUT high pgadmin4/email
    debconf (developer): --> 30 question skipped
    debconf (developer): <-- INPUT high pgadmin4/password
    debconf (developer): --> 30 question skipped
    debconf (developer): <-- GO 
    debconf (developer): --> 0 ok
    debconf (developer): <-- STOP
    debconf (developer): starting /tmp/xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04.config.rG27Za configure 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1~18.04.1
    setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file
    debconf (developer): <-- SET xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users Console Users Only
    debconf (developer): --> 0 value set
    debconf (developer): <-- INPUT low xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users
    debconf (developer): --> 30 question skipped
    debconf (developer): <-- GO 
    debconf (developer): --> 0 ok
    debconf (developer): <-- GET xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users
    debconf (developer): --> 0 Console Users Only
    debconf (developer): <-- SET xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/actual_allowed_users console
    debconf (developer): --> 0 value set
    dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
     unable to open files list file for package 'transmission-gtk': Permission denied
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: I guess this is due to some failed upgrade earlier?
Have you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then this command?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it won't fix it.